# Insert item at the beginning of dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm using a dictionary to populate a Select box in a view. All of that is working correctly. However, I need to add an additional option to the beginning of the dictionary that will act as a prompt to the user and have a value of -1.

I have the following code...

```
Dictionary<int, string> acctMgr = new Dictionary<int, string>();
acctMgr = db.Users.Where(u => u.Title.Contains("Account Manager") || u.Title.Contains("Client Services Manager")).ToDictionary(v => v.ApplicationUserId, v => v.FullName);
```

...and tried to add

```
acctMgr.Add(-1, "Choose one");
```

...but that adds it to the end of the list (I don't believe dictionaries are/can be sorted). After that, I tried to add the above line after the variable declaration, but it is replaced by the db.Users... line.

Thoughts?

Comment: A dictionary in itself isn't ordered. You are not using the right collection. Try looking at [SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx), that is, if you really want to use a Dictionary. I don't feel like this is the good type of collections for your problem. If you want to elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish, we might be able to guide you.

Comment: Use `SortedDictionary<>` or `SortedList<>`

Comment: Can you just do the adding of "Choose One" to the SelectBox before you fill it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries are not ordered - they are effectively a Hashtable structure that provides O(1) direct lookups. Therefore you are using the wrong data structure for an ordered collection. You might be better off with a `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` as the List will respect the order that items are added/inserted.

Comment: That wouldn't work in Trevor's case. He's adding `-1` after, and will be at the bottom of the list.

Comment: List supports `Insert(int index, T item)` that allows you to insert at any index. More: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx

Comment: Yes, he can insert at the first index. However, that's an O(n) insert. Using a sorted collection will do it in O(log n).

Comment: The List can maintain order via `BinarySearch` function when adding using ones complement... This would result in an O(log n) add and get. See my blog post for details: http://www.haneycodes.net/make-mostly-read-seldom-written-lists-much-more-efficient/

Comment: It can, but any insert will still be at O(n) because he needs to make sure everything keep an ordering. While your solution do work, I feel like thats re-inventing the wheel when there's ordered collection in the BCL.

Comment: @SimonBelanger: I am pretty sure that performance isn't an issue here.

Comment: My solution is more efficient than the SortedList for a few reasons that I won't discuss here... Ultimately it would be an O(log n) insert AND retrieval. Read my blog post before replying please.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Admittedly, there is nothing in the question that would leave us to believe it is. We don't know how that collection will be use and how often insertion/removal will happen.

Comment: A sorted list will provide O(log n) retrieval, but O(n) insert. This is because it must shift all the elements after the one being inserted down to the next position which takes O(n) time (average number of elements moved would be n/2).
That being said, in this case it doesnt really matter because as currently stated, the remaining elements dont need to be sorted so this will be a single O(n) operation while keeping a sorted list will have `n` O(log n) operations.

Comment: @Cemafor I just looked and SortedList is indeed implemented using arrays. Really thought it was using AVL / RBT. Then in this case, insertion is definitely O(n). +1 to this answer.

Comment: @SimonBelanger: I was refering to a list that happend to be sorted (and using binary search/insert) in my comment, but I guess it applies to an actual SortedList as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend manually adding the "Choose one" item to the control itself. This will make it easier to identify if a real selection has been made if the selection box is required.

However, if you are set on adding an item to a Dictionary of some sort, you could create your own extention method with the same signature as the `ToDictionary` method you are currently using but return a `SortedDictionary`.